# Elementary Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question is $A\!\setminus \!B = A\cap B^C$ always true? Given that the definition for $A\!\setminus \!B := \lbrace{x \in A \mid x \notin B\rbrace}$ and that  $A\cap B^C:=\lbrace{x\mid x \in A \text{ and } x \in B^C\rbrace}$ I can't see why they would be different. If they are equal, when does one choose one notation over the other?

Comment: At least one advantage of the first is that $A \setminus B$ is always defined, whereas $B^{c}$ requires there to be a universal set in order to make sense. If the universal set contains both $A$ and $B$ (as it should), then they are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $A \setminus B$ is always equal to $A \cap B^{c}$ (assuming we are in some larger "universal" set, as Dave mentioned).  In some scenarios, the fact that these two sets are equal is useful.

If you happen to know anything about $\sigma$-algebras and measure theory, then the key to proving that if $A$ and $B$ are in a $\sigma$-algebra, so is $A \setminus B$ is by knowing $A \setminus B = A \cap B^{c}$.

By the way -- notationally, you can represent this concept in three different ways.  $A \setminus B$, $A \cap B^{c}$, and $A - B$.  A lot of people like to use $A - B$ ($A$ minus $B$) because it is the most intuitive of the three "notations".

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by a larger "universal" set?

Comment: A reason not to use the notation $A-B$ for $\{x\in A:x\notin B\}$ is to avoid confusion with the Minkowski difference $A-B=\{a-b:a\in A,b\in B\}$.

Comment: @certainlyUncertain By a universal set, we mean the biggest set in the context you are talking about, where all of the sets you are talking about are subsets of this big set.  For example, you could take your "universal set" to be $\mathbb{R}$, the set of real numbers.  Then, after declaring your universal set, any time you are talking about a different set, it's assumed to be a subset of the universal set.

Comment: @certainlyUncertain For example, we could take the universal set to be $\mathbb{R}$ and then talk about its subsets.  If $A$ is a subset, then it would make sense to talk about $A^{c}$.  $A^{c}$ is the set of elements of $\mathbb{R}$, our universal set, that are not in $A$.  If we don't define the universal set, but we still say $A$ is a set of numbers, then what would $A^{c}$ be?  Since $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, if we don't define the universal set, then $A^{c}$ could either mean the set of *real* numbers not in $A$, or the set of *complex* numbers not in $A$...

Comment: @user46944 Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @certainlyUncertain So stating what your universal set is before you start talking about subsets is very important.  Otherwise, taking the complement of a set doesn't make sense.  Again, to reiterate this point, suppose we say $A = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, \dots \}$.  But we don't say what our universal set is.  Then what is $A^{c}$?  It doesn't make sense to talk about the complement.  But if we say our universal set is $\mathbb{Z}$, the set of integers, then $A^{c} = \{ -1, -2, -3, \dots \}$.  If our universal set if $\mathbb{R}$, then $A^{c} = (-\infty, 0) \cup (0, 1) \cup (1,2) \cup \dots$.